# POST to ASP during authentication not redirecting to asp form

Tags: authentication, asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

POST to ASP.NET during authentication not redirecting to asp.net form.  We have a login.asp page 
[image]

The GO button is a submit to a loginproc.asp that is in a subfolder of the website.

The program hangs like it cant find loginprocesing.asp.  This happen after added many security patches to a Win2008 R2 server running IIS 7.5.

The network in debugging

```
1.  Request URL:
    https://sees.tmp.com/CorpTrip3/common/LoginProc.asp
2.  Request Headers
1.  Provisional headers are shown
2.  Accept:
    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
3.  Content-Type:
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
4.  Origin:
    https://sees.tmp.com
5.  Referer:
    https://sees.tmp.com/CorpTrip3/Login.asp
```

So we get an error

```
Failed to open https://sees.tmp.com/CorpTrip3/common/LoginProc.asp.
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

It was not just a code problem but also a setting in IIS. This app was using its own(arrrgh) session variables.